# Functional interfaces introduced in java 8

Tags: java

I have been asked in a interview below qn:

Which of the following functional interfaces were currently introduced in  Java 8:

1. Runnable
2. List
3. Callable
4. Collection

I dont think anyone of them were introduced in Java 8. These interfaces were present before Java 8.

java.util.function.* was introduced which have some new interfaces like java.util.function.Predicate, java.util.function.Consumer.

Please suggest whether this question is correct or not

Comment: Note that the Javadoc for old versions of Java are still available online, so you can easily check that all of these existed in Java 7 -- see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html -- but that not all of them are functional interfaces.

Comment: That is what I was saying in Qn above. None of the ans seems correct, if they were just asking about newly added interface. If its about existing interface, the no issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While all of these interfaces existed prior to Java 8, 2 of them - `Runnable` and `Callable` - were annotated as `@FunctionalInterface` since Java 8. That said, this annotation is informative, and even without it, they can be used as functional interfaces (which means they can be implemented by a lambda expression or a method reference) since Java 8.

The other two are not functional interfaces, since they have multiple abstract methods.